# How do you access pods through a service?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment with 2 replicas. I can access the pods via curl.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I created a service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

I was expecting to be able to access the pods through the service via the EndPoints but the result I get is.

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here better?

kubectl get svc

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP   2d23h
nginx-service   ClusterIP   10.109.19.46   <none>        80/TCP    22h
```

curl --insecure https://PUBLICIP:6443

Comment: Could you please update 1) `kubectl get svc` 2) The `curl/wget` command you are trying to access service  3) From where you are trying the `curl` command. ?

Comment: Added it above, looks like curl 10.109.19.46 works. I'm probably misunderstanding the IP used to access it.

Comment: There's an authorisation failure. You are not authenticating as a regular user but just as the "anonymous" user. Please add to the question the command you're executing that returns the above result.

Answer (score 1):

With your command you're trying to access the `/` path of the Kubernetes API, but it fails because you're not supplying any credentials to the request:

```sh
curl --insecure https://PUBLICIP:6443
```

But anyway, if you want to access the Pods behind the Service, you don't need to access the Kubernetes API, but you need to access the exposed Service.

A ClusterIP service as in your example (the default) cannot be accessed from outside the cluster. If you want to access the Service from outside the cluster, you need to create, for example, a NodePort Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

And then you can access the Service (and thus the Pods behind it) through the IP address and NodePort of one of the worker nodes:

```sh
curl NODE_IP:NODE_PORT
```

You can get the `NODE_IP` of one of the nodes with `kubectl get nodes -o wide` and the `NODE_PORT` of the Service with `kubectl get svc nginx-service`.

Comment: I was first trying to access through the service. After that I was going to try an ingress.

Comment: You don't need an Ingress, you just need a Service other than ClusterIP. For example NodePort.

Answer (score 1):

The `curl` command you are using will hit the `Kubernetes API server` (defaults to `6443` port) ; NOT the service you created.

The `nginx-service` you created will create a `ClusterIP` service, which will not be accessible from outside. You have to use either `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` type service.

To access your service, you can try below (using `NodePort`)

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: NodePort
```

Then get the `NodePort` from `kubectl get svc`

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP   2d23h
nginx-service   NodePort    10.109.19.46   <none>        80:32474/TCP    22h <<<-- (NodePort is 32474)
```

You can use any node's IP and the port 32474 combinations to access the service.

Eg:-

`curl http://192.168.10.10:32474`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to expose the service as `"NodePort"` using `kubectl`,

Initially, you have to delete the existing service,

```
kubectl delete svc nginx-service //if you have a namespace -n yourNameSpace
```

Then expose your deployment as "NodePort" as following,

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-deployment --port=80 --type=NodePort --name=nginx-service //if you have a namespace -n yourNameSpace
```

Now the "NodePort" service has been created and you could curl to the service through,

```
curl NODE_IP:NODE_PORT
```